# Python 3: How to transfer text based game into a GUI?

Tags: python

I'm new to programming, and Python is the first language I'm learning. Is it a way to transfer a text-based game into a GUI, or how do I get a text-based game in a GUI? I want to have my game in the GUI instead of the console. Im currently using spyder as my text editor, and its in-built console, but I want to have what's happening in the console when I run the program, just in a GUI.

Sorry if it's hard to understand what I mean, but I do hope you can help me!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Share your research, so we can help you better.

Answer (score 0):

If you're new to Python an new to GUIs then maybe [PySimpleGUI](https://pysimplegui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) is the way for you to go.  If you can draw the GUI on a piece of paper, you can code it up in PySimpleGUI.  What do you need it to do?